# How to append default value for optional argument in argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using `argparse` and I know that for a particular argument I can set `action='append'` and then every time I set that argument the value gets appended, e.g.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", type=int, action="append")
args = parser.parse_args(["-a", "5", "-a", "6"])
print(args)
```

the output to this is:

```
Namespace(a=[5, 6])
```

For my application I would like to type in an argument name `-img` followed by sub-arguments, `path` a positional sub-argument of type string and `val` an optional sub-argument of type int which defaults to zero.
So, corresponding to code:

```
args = parser.parse_args(["-img", "/path-to-img-0", "5", 
                          "-img", "/path-to-img-1"])
```

I would like to get:

```
args = Namespace(path=["/path-to-img-0", "/path-to-img-1"],
                 val=[5, 0])
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: `argparse` can give you `Namespace(img =[ ["/path-to-img-0","5"],["/path-to-img-1"]])`, with `append` and `nargs='*'.  In other words, append produces a list, `nargs` also produces a list, hence lists within a list.

Comment: thanks for the reply @hpaulj, wouldn't that be a bad practice, since the user could enter a string or float instead of int as the second sub-argument? also, we wouldn't be able to assign a default value if second sub-argument is absent.

Comment: Those are details that your own handling of the resulting list has to deal with.  The parser hasn't lost any information.  It doesn't have a mechanism to accept say a string and an integer.  The `type` function applies to all strings; `nargs` just counts arguments.  You could write a custom `Action` class, but I think post-parsing handling is simpler.